# Uncaught Error: Unexpected module 'DataTableModule' declared by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation

Tags: angular, datatables

Everything is perfect when i try to run above error occurs.i have used npm install angular5-data-table --save and imported correctly but also getting error

Comment: Could you please share the `@NgModule` ?

Comment: i have imported this import { DataTableModule } from 'angular-4-data-table/src/index';